# General solution of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry

For any real numbers $x$ and $y$. $\sin x = \sin y \implies n\pi + (-1)^ny, $ where $n \in Z$

If $\sin x = \sin y$, then $\sin x -\sin y = 0$ 
or $2\cos\frac{x+y}{2}\sin \frac{x-y}{2} = 0$

$\Rightarrow \cos\frac{x+y}{2} = 0 ; \sin \frac{x-y}{2}=0$

Therefore  $\frac{x+y}{2} = (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} $ or $\frac{x-y}{2} = n\pi,$ where $n \in Z$

i.e. x $= (2n+1)\pi -y $ or $x = 2n\pi +y,$ where $n \in Z$

Please guide further

Comment: looks okay ... note that odd + even = whole, also put $x = n\pi + (-1)^ny$

Comment: What would you like? The statements after the i.e. seem pretty accurate and they are equivalent to $x = n\pi+(-1)^ny$.

Comment: how to get final result ie. $n\pi +(-1)^ny$